# how to get azimuth and elevation from enu vectors

Tags: gis, data-conversion, elevation, azimuth

How do you get the azimuth and elevation from one enu vector to another enu vector?

A link to a formula or piece of code would be helpful.  I'm not getting much information at all when searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the azimuth and elevation angles between East-North-Up vectors `(x,y,z)` and `(u,v,w)` using the following:

1. Subtract the vectors: `(x,y,z) - (u,v,w) = (x-u,y-v,z-w) = (x',y',z')`
2. Compute the azimuth angle: `a = arctan(x'/y') = arctan((x-u)/(y-v))`
3. Compute the elevation angle: `e = arctan(z'/y') = arctan((z-w)/(y-v))`

In Python:

```
v1 = np.array([3,4,4])
v2 = np.array([1,2,6])
v = v1 - v2

a = np.degrees(np.arctan(v[0]/v[1]))
e = np.degrees(np.arctan(v[2]/v[1]))

print('azimuth = '+str(a)+', elevation = '+str(e))
```

Output:

```
azimuth = 45.0, elevation = -45.0
```

[image: Azimuth and Elevation]

[(Image Source)](http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/techdoc/visualize/chview3.html)

Comment: What if `y'` is zero?

Comment: A bit late perhaps, but use np.arctan2(x, y) instead, it handles y = 0 just fine

Comment: Should z not be `arctan2(z', sqrt((y')^2 + (x')^2))`? Even if you look at the way this picture is drawn seems correct

Comment: @gkv I think you are correct. In the example the horizontal distance is `sqrt(2^2 + 2^2)`. The elevation angle should be `arctan2(2, sqrt(2^2 + 2^2))) = +/- 35.26`